# selecting comment in multiple comment in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm working in my post comment in rails and clicking the comment links makes my post comment open all

before clicking the comment link
[image]

after click my apps open all comment box
[image]

here is my post/index

```
          <div class="post-action" align="center">

                    <% if current_user.liked? post %>
                        <td>
                          <%= link_to 'unlike', {:controller => 'post', :id => post , :action =>'unlike'}, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>  
                        </td>
                    <% else %>
                        <td>
                         <%= link_to 'like', {:controller => 'post', :id => post , :action =>'like'}, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>  
                        </td>
                    <% end %>

                   <td>Likes:<%= post.votes_for.size%></td>

                   <hr>
                <div class="comment-action">
                  <%= link_to "Comments", "#", class: "comments-link" %>

                  <section class = "comments-section">
                  <br>
                    <%= render 'commenters/newsfeedcomment', obj: post %>

                    <% if current_user == post.user %>
                      <h6 align="right"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></h6>
                      <h6 align="right"><%= link_to 'Delete', { :id => post ,:controller => 'posts',:action => 'destroy'} %></h6>
                    <% end %>
                  </section>
                </div>    
          </div>
```

and this is my post.coffee

```
$(document).ready ->
$(".comments-link").click (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  $('.comments-section').fadeToggle()
  $('#commenter_body').focus()
```

i just want to open particular comment

Comment: pre, lahat kasi ng comment links mo pare sila ng class `class: "comments-link"`

Comment: mag loloop ako ng class? at ng JS ko?

Comment: kung same lahat ng class dapat gamitin `$(this)` para hindi lahat ma select. sagot ni Azemoh tama.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i solve my problem just want to share it with you guys and thanks for giving me an idea.

heres my code in the post/index

```
 <div class="comment-action">
                  <%= link_to "Comments", "#post_comments_#{post.id}" %>
                   <section class="comments-section" id="post_comments_<%= post.id %>"  >
                  <br>
                    <%= render 'commenters/newsfeedcomment', obj: post %>

                    <% if current_user == post.user %>
                      <h6 align="right"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></h6>
                      <h6 align="right"><%= link_to 'Delete', { :id => post ,:controller => 'posts',:action => 'destroy'} %></h6>
                    <% end %>

                </div>
```

and here the script that i need

```
$(document).on 'click', 'a[href^="#post_comments_"]', (event) ->
  event.preventDefault() && event.stopImmediatePropagation()
  $target = $($(@).attr('href'))
  $target.fadeToggle()
```

i hope this will help you someday

Answer (score 1):

As every post has `uniq id`, you can use the `id` value and take the class names based on these id values and you can refer them distinctly,

`Eg: <section class = "comments-section" id = "comments-section-<%= post.id %>">`

If we take this the id becomes `"comments-section-1","comments-section-2"`, etc unique values which you can refer later as,

`$('#comments-section-'+id).fadeToggle()`

```
<div class="post-action" align="center">

  <% if current_user.liked? post %>
      <td>
        <%= link_to 'unlike', {:controller => 'post', :id => post , :action =>'unlike'}, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>  
      </td>
  <% else %>
      <td>
       <%= link_to 'like', {:controller => 'post', :id => post , :action =>'like'}, class: "btn btn-xs btn-danger" %>  
      </td>
  <% end %>

 <td>Likes:<%= post.votes_for.size%></td>

  <hr>
  <div class="comment-action">
    <%= link_to "Comments", "#", class: "comments-link" id: post.id%>

    <section class = "comments-section" id = "comments-section-<%= post.id %>">
    <br>
      <%= render 'commenters/newsfeedcomment', obj: post %>

      <% if current_user == post.user %>
        <h6 align="right"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></h6>
        <h6 align="right"><%= link_to 'Delete', { :id => post ,:controller => 'posts',:action => 'destroy'} %></h6>
      <% end %>
    </section>
  </div>    
</div>
```

**Script(observe the addition of id)**

```
  $(document).ready ->
  $(".comments-link").click (event) ->
  id_val = this.id
  event.preventDefault()
  $('#comments-section-'+id_val).fadeToggle()
  $('#commenter_body').focus()
```

Comment: sorry for my late reply i was so tired yesterday because of this problem i will try this thanks for sharing your knowledge

Comment: i had an error SyntaxError: [stdin]:6:6: reserved word 'var'
but your explanation give me more sense to me now thanks @Sravan great help

Comment: just change id to id_val, I changed in js please check.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `$(this)` to target the element that was clicked

```
$(".comments-link").click (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    $(this).find('.comments-section').fadeToggle()
    $(this).find('#commenter_body').focus()
```

See more examples here http://html-tuts.com/jquery-this-selector/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're using the same html class for all your comment boxes. There are several ways around, however here is an approach I'd probably follow:

```
<div class="comment-action">
 <%= link_to "Comments", "#", class: "comments-link", data: {toggle: "post-#{post.id}-comments-section"} %>
 <section class = "comments-section" data-toggleclass="post-#{post.id}-comments-section"><br>
  <%= render 'commenters/newsfeedcomment', obj: post %>
  <% if current_user == post.user %>
   <h6 align="right">
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %>
   </h6>
   <h6 align="right">
    <%= link_to 'Delete', { :id => post ,:controller => 'posts',:action => 'destroy'} %>
   </h6>
  <% end %>
 </section>
</div> 


$(document).ready ->
$(".comments-link").click (event) ->
  event.preventDefault()
  toggleAttr = $(this).attr('data-toggle')
  $("section[data-toggleclass='" + toggleAttr +"']").fadeToggle()
  $('#commenter_body').focus()
```

Comment: posting another approach shortly

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $$ is not defined